# Printing the Nth column to the Mth column

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to print the N<sup>th</sup> column to the M<sup>th</sup> column of a table; for example:

```
1 2 3 ... n ... m ...
X & $     #     !
@ $ %     (     *
```

to

```
n ... m 
#     !
(     *
```

Comment: How is the table?. Delimiter?. Example line(s)?. Example of extracted columns?. What have you tried?.

Comment: I did not use the command until the end because I want the result to be only until the mth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a perl one-liner

```
perl -slane 'print join " ", @F[$n-1 .. $m-1]' -- -n=5 -m=8 file
```

Comment: nice. i had completely forgotten that perl's `-s` option existed.  that's odd - `man perlrun` says that the switches need to be before `--` or any filename args, but `--` means the end of perl's own options, so any `-s` options should come after the `--`.

Comment: If I was using a script name instead of `-e body` it would be different

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean that you want to print between two columns such as from the 4th column to the 10th column?

If so:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 4-8 table.txt
```

That will print columns 4-8.  `cut` will work well for this problem as long as the column delimiter is a single character.

*Edit* The cat wasn't necessary and I changed the delimiter to a space to fit your table.